# How do i delete a specific item by it's id with react and the fetch method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express

Hey so i've been trying to get this code to work but i can't seem to figure out one last thing and that's how i delete items in my database with the fetch method.

I want to get the id from the current clicked item and delete it with the deletebutton i created.

```
class Datatest extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todolist: []
    }
    this.addTodo = this.addTodo.bind(this);
  }
  // GET items from API
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/api/todolist')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((results)=> {    
      console.log(results)
      this.setState({todolist:results})
    })   
}

  deleteTodo(id){

      fetch('/api/todolist/' + id, {
          method: 'DELETE',
          mode: 'CORS'
      }).then(res => res)
  }


  render() {
    // mapping through todolist items
    const todo = this.state.todolist.map((item) => (
      <div className="todoitem" key={item._id}>
        <h3>{ item._id }</h3>
        <div className="delete-button"><img src={trashcan} alt="trashcan" onClick={this.deleteTodo} /></div>
      </div>

    ));
    return (
      <div className="test">
        <div className="todoitems-container">
          {todo}
          <div className="delete-item"></div>  
        </div>
        <form onSubmit={this.addTodo}>
          <input type="text" ref="title" />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Datatest;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an arrow function to call the handler with your id:

```js
const todo = this.state.todolist.map((item) => (
    <div className="todoitem" key={item._id}>
        <h3>{ item._id }</h3>
        <div className="delete-button">
            <img 
                src={trashcan} 
                alt="trashcan" 
                onClick={() => this.deleteTodo(item._id)}
            />
        </div>
    </div>
));
```

This will create an anonymous handler function for every item in your array that calls your handler with the correct id.

Comment: Inline function binding can affect performance and isn’t recommended, bind once in the constructor.

Comment: @James The handler must be dynamically generated as the todo list (and therefore the id it has to be called with) can change at arbitrary time. How is this supposed to work in the constructor? This is for sure an exception from this rule. You could of course extract the item logic into an own component to avoid this. For reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers

Comment: not necessarily, you could set the ID as a data attribute and then extract the value in the event handler which would only need a single bind. The correct approach however is, as you’ve suggested, to move this into its own component (as outlined in my answer).

Comment: @James I don't see why it would be a better approach to pollute the DOM with application data. Also using an arrow function to pass additional arguments to a handler inside a loop is the recommended way to do it. It's even in the react docs. See [Passing Arguments to Event Handlers](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers). The performance penalty is marginal if you do not render thousands of nodes. I call that premature optimization. And in that case you should probably extract it as a component instead of using data attributes.

Comment: I didn’t say it’s better I simply gave you an option of not rebinding the handler on each render, also FWIW you aren’t necessarily polluting the DOM (`id` would be an ideal natural DOM `id`). However, yes, it is dependant on the no. of items in the list before it becomes a performance problem but it’s generally recommended to avoid inline binding if you can (which is certainly doable in this case).

Comment: @James Using the `id` of the DOM element is even more terrible that using data-attributes (which are known to have poor performance too). `is`'s are meant to be used to uniquely identify a DOM element (for selecting it in query selectors). As object id's are commonly integers chances are you end up having multiple DOM elements with the same `id` if you use this approach in other components too. This is even more of an anti-pattern. You are way to dogmatic about "generally not recommended". In fact arrow functions **are the recommended way** to do this.

Comment: @James It usually only becomes a problem to dynamically bind handlers when you pass them further down the react tree as they will trigger re-renders on children of the children too. [And for the reference I will repeately link the official react docs again, that suggest exactly this to pass additional arguments to handlers](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers). So please do not repeatedly state that this is not recommended.

Comment: you seem to be fixating on irrelevant points e.g. if you use non-unique IDs for model IDs then I'd argue your model is wrong....Anyway, not to digress, the point I was making is in this case I don't agree that arrow functions is the correct solution, it comes with a performance penalty that a. you haven't explained and b. can be avoided. The component is polluted and needs modularised, it's the React way, *if* there was absolutely no way around this then I would agree with you...but there is, so I don't, and that's ok - it's just my opinion :)

Comment: @James You missunderstood me there. Of course every item in a model has a unique id. But an item of another model may have the same id, e.g. a user with id 5 and a gallery picture item with also id 5. So if you are consistently using that approach all over your react app you will end up having multiple DOM elements with that same id. The id attribute is not meant to store model id's. It should be a unique verbose string that describes the purpose of the DOM element. Something like e.g. `twitter-follow-button` but not `5`.

Comment: @James The performance costs are marginal and in programming it is **generally not recommended** (because you like this term so much) to optimize code that is not proven to be too slow. This pattern is widely used and in 99% of the cases does not cause a performance problem. An this is also exactly what the react docs state about this.

Comment: your example about the DOM ID is tailored to suit your argument, GUIDs are probably a more commonly used ID these days for models than integers which negates your point. Anyway, I don't want to descend into a debate on what is and isn't a good DOM ID, I was merely making a point. *"it is generally not recommended to optimize code that is not proven to be slow"* - it's also not *recommended* to make assumptions about code you haven't tested, but here we are. Regardless, using composition here isn't micro-optimising, it's the *right* way, *in my opinion* of course :)

Comment: @James If we can agree that extracting list items to own components is the recommended and react way to do it I'm with you to bring that discussion to an end. :) But i can't agree with abusing the DOM elements id attribute. In my opinion you should not make assumptions about the nature of id's other than that they are unique for a specific model especially if you do not own the code that produces them which is not enough to assume they are unique all over your application which disqualifies them to be DOM id's.

Comment: agreed. However, FWIW I also don't advocate "abusing" DOM elements either, my original point was *"a model ID would be a natural a DOM ID"*...that is of course in my head assuming the model ID would be unique in this case, completely take the point that that isn't always the case so I could've worded that more explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Either of these should work:

```
    <div className="delete-button"><img src={trashcan} alt="trashcan" onClick={(e) => this.deleteTodo(item._id, e} /></div>
```

or:

```
    <div className="delete-button"><img src={trashcan} alt="trashcan" onClick={this.deleteTodo.bind(this, item._id)} /></div>
```

Comment: Inline function binding can affect performance and isn’t recommended, bind once in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The React way would be to modularise your view by creating the relevant components - in your case, I would recommend creating both a `<TodoItem />` and `<TodoList />` component e.g.

```
class TodoItem extends PureComponent {

  handleDeleteClick = () => this.props.onDelete(this.props.id)

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="todoitem">
        <h3>{this.props.id}</h3>
        <div className="delete-button"><img src={trashcan} alt="trashcan" onClick={this.handleDeleteClick} /></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class TodoList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="test">
        <div className="todoitems-container">
          {this.props.items.map(i => <TodoItem
            key={i._id}
            id={i._id}
            onDelete={this.props.onDeleteItem}
          />)}
          <div className="delete-item"></div>  
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Datatest extends Component {

  deleteTodo(id){
    fetch(`/api/todolist/${id}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      mode: 'CORS'
    }).then(res => res)
  }

  render() {
    return <TodoList 
      items={this.state.todolist}
      onDeleteItem={this.deleteTodo}
    />;
  }
}
```

This type of approach allows you to also segment the responsibility i.e. the `TodoItem` takes care of propagating the UI events for itself, the `TodoList` takes care of propagating the model changes to the container.

The [Redux](https://redux.js.org) pattern works very well with React, worth having a look.